# Under what conditions is Monkey King visible when on a tree?

Tags: dota-2

The just-released [patch 7.00](http://www.dota2.com/700) brings a new hero [Monkey King](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Monkey_King). With his Tree Dance ability, he can jump onto a tree, and onward from tree to tree.

This "being on a tree" state is completely new to the game.  Trees are visible, but they also block vision.  Does that mean Monkey King is visible or invisible when on a tree?  Are there conditions when he is or isn't visible when on a tree, or leaping between them?  How does this interact with ground/flying vision and True Sight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While perched on a tree, Monkey King is hidden from sight. **He can only be seen with flying vision**.

> Flying vision gives unrestricted vision in an area, so it is not blocked by trees or obstacles and can see all elevations.

[**Sources of Flying Vision**](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Vision#Flying_vision)

- Towers do not have flying vision <s>and the ranged creep has flying vision</s> so be careful when you are perched on a tree near a lane.
- Monkey King can also be seen when standing 2 levels of ground higher than the tree he sits on, allowing wards to spot him when the ward is on an elevated ward spot.
- However, he cannot be seen when getting hurled in the air by spells (e.g. Toss). Only standing on high ground may grant vision over him.

Another important thing to note is that although Monkey King is shown to be at an elevation he is still considered to be on the ground. The height is part of the animations. Hence spells like Mirana's arrow and Io's spirits affect Monkey King.

- Monkey King is not invisible when on a tree so **true sight is not required**.
- **He is visible while jumping between trees even to grounded units**.
- During the leap and while on a tree, Monkey King gains flying vision, but has his vision reduced to 800. (Moonshard affects his vision but Nightstalker's Darkness does not)

Answer (score 3):

**If Monkey King is not moving, consider Monkey King to be [<s>1</s>](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Monkey_King&oldid=1376051) 2 levels higher.**  If you (or a ward) are two steps higher than the tree he is standing on, then you can see him.

**If he is moving, then he is on the same level as you, but vision can still be blocked by trees.**

Flying vision always works, as well as other sources of vision.

And of course, the best solution is to pick Timbersaw and stun him :)

Comment: @Vylix That's actually a buff he got.  [Back in 2016, it was 1 level higher](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Monkey_King&oldid=1376051) :P

Answer (score 0):

Just to add. Vengeful spirit's wave of terror reveals monkey king in a tree for a split second, then he disappears again even tho the waves' vision is still present.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put a **ward near the tree** and you can see him also you are able to **use any spell/ulti** on him.

Even you can hit him. Its not like there is ward on uphill and you can't break it if you are melee. If you see monkey king on tree after placing ward, just hit him or ulti like dual, repture stun anything.

I just played last night and did all those things that's why i can say these things are working.

Comment: This is wrong. Putting a ward near the tree won't give sight of perched MK, unless the ward is on elevated ground. For current patch, the ward needs to be two level higher than the terrain where the tree is. This usually means hill wards in 5 locations (dire jungle top, radiant jungle mid, radiant jungle bot, 2 spots in dire jungle bot)

Comment: @Vylix thank you for your comment but you are talking about current patch which change time to time..at that time when i gave answer it was easy to see the monkey with help of ward.when you are going to plant the ward, it will show the yellow area which will be unrevealed mk position.Not sure why you gave dw but thank you

Comment: DV is for wrong answer. I have nothing personal against you. Ward on the same level of the ground as the tree MK perched on never reveal him, from the first patch when he came around, until current patch. If it was an outdated information, I'll just tell you, but this is just wrong, not outdated.

Comment: @Vylix i think you are not getting my point. When i am placing ward i can see yellow background which will reveal every object(not invi) of that particular area no matter if mk is on higher tree or not.If that area is covered in yellow background then we can easily see mk. Last night i played against mk and i did that thats why i am saying this. And you are talking about hill wards then let me tell you that will only reveal some part but if mk is in bottom tower and if i will put ward near secret shop then i can see mk.